# MySQL IF Statement Updating MySQL Column

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Hello i am having a problem with mysql i'm not really that good at mysql but i wanted to update a column every minute so i was writing a event to update the column every minute but i am having problems with the code?

```
SELECT * FROM resources

IF wood < warehouse THEN
    UPDATE `resources` SET `wood`= wood + 10
ELSE
    UPDATE `resources` SET `wood`= wood
END IF;

IF stone < warehouse THEN
    UPDATE `resources` SET `stone`= stone + 10
ELSE
    UPDATE `resources` SET `stone`= stone
END IF;

IF metal < warehouse THEN
    UPDATE `resources` SET `metal`= metal + 10
ELSE
    UPDATE `resources` SET `metal`= metal
END IF;
```

I am really hoping that you can do if statements because i wanted to update the wood,stone,metal but not have it goes over the warehouse space limit? Any clues?

Comment: Question is not very clear .

Comment: why is your `ELSE` cases? They do nothing.

Comment: `but not have it goes over the warehouse space limit?` what does it mean? o.O

Comment: Sorry i may not have been to clear, i am making a game and every minute they get resources and there warehouse can only hold a curtain amount say 1000 and every minute they get 10 wood, when there wood capacity reaches 1000 i don't want it to run the update script anymore so that it doesn't go over the warehouse limit until they build another warehouse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL supports the [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html) condition in an `UPDATE` statement. Your statements could look like this:

```
UPDATE  `ressources`
SET     `wood` = IF(wood < warehouse, wood + 10, wood),
        `stone` = IF(stone < warehouse, stone + 10, stone),
        `metal` = IF(metal < warehouse, metal + 10, metal);
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i wanted thank you so much have been stuck on it for days haha.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
UPDATE `resources` 
SET `wood`= IF(wood < warehouse, wood + 10, wood),
stone = IF(stone < warehouse, stone + 10, stone),
...;
```